# Concurrent execution of multiple networks in TensorFlow

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to figure out which is the best way to run multiple pre-trained models for inference in TensorFlow (in the context of single-machine execution). I read several questions about this, but I'm still a bit confused.
For example, let us assume to run 2 deep networks in 2 different processes/threads.
To my understanding, I can do this either:

- Running the two models within the same session (i.e., two processes which shares a single session), or
- running two different sessions, one for each network/process, or
- using TensorFlow Serving.

If I run this in a platform consisting of only a multi-core CPU, I imagine that the difference (from an execution point of view) is that with a single session there is a single intra op thread pool and
a single inter pool thread pool, whereas in the second case they are distinct.

How does TensorFlow Serving modify the way in which the networks are executed on CPUs?

To my understanding, there is a benefit in using it when TensorFlow is used with GPUs, since it groups individual inference requests for joint execution.

In heterogenous architectures, does TF Serving adopt a different graph partitioning among device with respect to the one used in training (i.e., the one described in the TensorFlow White Paper)?

Among these three possibilities, which one is actually adopted in production environments?

If there are some specific documents that I missed which describe this characteristics of TensorFlow, please point me to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

you likely don’t want the same device placement used for serving as you did for training.

in fact, when you export/save your tensorflow model for serving, you can specify ‘clear_devices=true’ (or similar).

we prefer TF serving over the other 2 methods mentioned above.  and we experiment with cpu/gpu/tpu for each and every new model that we build.

and while we always have an intuition about the best hardware, we always test our models in live production to learn the model’s empirical behavior.

we’re also experimenting with different runtimes like TensorRT from Nvidia (gpu) and different post-training optimization techniques like TensorFlow Lite (tfcompile).

we use PipelineAI for our TensorFlow model experimentation, optimization, and cluster deployments:

https://github.com/PipelineAI/pipeline